# Invalid Property Value error for Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried going through multiple threads to find an answer that I need but not able to sort it out yet.

I have certain combo boxes in my userform and I have a button to upload the details. Once the details are uploaded in my excel sheet, I want the form to clear all the contents and reset to blanks. The data is getting updated perfectly in the excel file, however each time I get an error stating Invalid Property Value. I want to be able to upload the details without getting the error. I have tried setting the combo box style to list, however, it still gives me the same error

Also if the user selects a value in the combo box and later deletes it then the same message is again popped up and the user can't move to another filed until he selects a value from the list. I want the user to be able to delete the entry or select only from the list (that's why I have the match required set to True).

Can someone please guide

PFB the code :

```
Private Sub CmdUploadDatabaseDetails_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\anup.patil\Desktop\Dashboard 
    Testing.xlsx")
    wb.Activate
    IsEntryBlank = CheckIfBlanksDatabase

    If IsEntryBlank = True Then
        MsgBox "Please fill all the mandatory details"
        wb.Close False 
        cwb.Activate
        Me.CBMonth.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Sheets("Database").Select
    Range("B1").End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Lastrow = Sheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(Lastrow + 1, 1).Select

    ActiveCell.Value = Me.CBMonth.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.TBParentCo.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value = Me.TBSubsidaryCo.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 4).Value = Me.CBCustomerCat.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 5).Value = Me.TBContactName.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 6).Value = Me.TBDesignation.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 7).Value = Me.TBDept.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 8).Value = Me.CBVertical.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 9).Value = Me.CBSubVertical.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 10).Value = Me.TBOperatingLoc.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 11).Value = Me.TBNearbyHKVBr.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 12).Value = Me.TBOperatingLocAddr.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 13).Value = Me.CBOperatingLocState.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 15).Value = Me.CBDecisionMakingUnit.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 16).Value = Me.TBHOCentralized.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 17).Value = Me.TBMobileNo.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 18).Value = Me.TBPhoneNo.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 19).Value = Me.TBEmail.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 20).Value = Me.CBRelationshipBuild.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 21).Value = Me.TBMemberOfAssoc.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 22).Value = Me.TBListOfEmpanelled.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 23).Value = Me.CBGiftAllowed.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 24).Value = Me.CBGiftDeliveryMode.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 25).Value = Me.TBSurvPotential.Text

    Me.CBMonth.ListIndex = -1
    Me.CBMonth.Value = ""
    Me.TBParentCo.Value = ""
    Me.TBSubsidaryCo.Value = ""
    Me.CBCustomerCat.Value = ""
    Me.TBContactName.Value = ""
    Me.TBDesignation.Value = ""
    Me.TBDept.Value = ""
    Me.CBVertical.Value = ""
    Me.CBSubVertical.Value = ""
    Me.TBOperatingLoc.Value = ""
    Me.TBNearbyHKVBr.Value = ""
    Me.TBOperatingLocAddr.Value = ""
    Me.CBOperatingLocState.Value = ""
    Me.CBDecisionMakingUnit.Value = ""
    Me.TBHOCentralized.Value = ""
    Me.TBMobileNo.Value = ""
    Me.TBPhoneNo.Value = ""
    Me.TBEmail.Value = ""
    Me.CBRelationshipBuild.Value = ""
    Me.TBMemberOfAssoc.Value = ""
    Me.TBListOfEmpanelled.Value = ""
    Me.CBGiftAllowed.Value = ""
    Me.CBGiftDeliveryMode.Value = ""
    Me.TBSurvPotential.Value = ""

    Me.CBMonth.SetFocus

    wb.Close True

    MsgBox "Details uploaded successfully"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peh, its not any error that i am getting in a code. I just need to find a workaround for the invalid property value pop up i get after i leave a combo box blank. I have tried. Hence my question doesn't have any code. I have stated what i have tried and what output i want to achieve as well. Do let me know if i still have to show the code

Comment: Obviously the error shows up because something is wrong in your code (what else would produce the error if not the code?). So if we don't see the code we cannot say what you did wrong. Please also include the *exact* error message.

Comment: when you get the message, press `ctrl+break`. This should bring you to the faulty line.

Comment: Hi PEH, Have updated the code as well. The error is occurring because i am setting the Combo box values to blank after the details are uploaded and that is because i have the match required set to true for the combo boxes. I just want to combo box to accept the blank values once details are uploaded. Need a workaround for that

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I am not getting the error on any particular line. Its just that i am getting a message box stating "Invalid Property Value" and once clicked on Ok or close i am able to fill another entries

Comment: It has been three years now and by now you might have got the answer. Been wondering why not clear the combobox rather than setting it to an empty string ?

Answer (score 0):

Set MatchingRequired to False for the combobox.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).